# Error: Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a function which receives 8-byte data on UART and I am using one of the data byte in a way that I read that data byte and call a function that modulates the volume of the MP3 codec that I am going to use.
The MP3 codec function that sets the volume is a little weird that it sets the sound as if the input to it is 0x00, the 100% volume and if it happens to be 0x64 then its 0%.

Now, the LabVIEW firmware is set up (by some other developer in team) in such a manner that if it wants to set the volume to be 100% then it sends 0x64, and 0x00 for 0%, through the UART into the data byte that I am going to read, as I said above.

Avoiding the complications on this post, what I have tried to do is, to implement a simple C code that would take the input from console and print the processed output. Say if input is 0x00, then the output should be 0x64 and if input happens to be 0x64 then output should be 0x00.
Following is the code that I have written, in which I am getting the Error that says:

```
Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall
```

The code below may appear to be very inefficient and of very basic level, but that is for the sake of understanding.

```
int main(void)
{
   int input = 0x00, output = 0x00, i = 0x00, j = 0x64, var = 0x00;
   int in_arr[100], out_arr[100];

   for(i = 0x00; i < 0x65; i++, j--)
   { 
     out_arr[i] = j;
     in_arr[i] = i;
   }

   printf("Input : ");
   scanf("%x",&input);

   for(var = 0x00; var < 0x64; var++)
   {
     if(input == in_arr[var])
     {
       output = out_arr[var];
       printf("0x%x",output);
       break;
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i = 0x00; i < 0x65; i++, j--)   // Should be i < 0x64
```

Here `i` can have maximum of 101 elements (0 to 100) since `0x65 => 101` but declared to contain only `100` elements.

Make it as `i < 0x64` and it should work.

To avoid such confusions, the best is to have macro as `#define MAX_ELE 100` and use `MAX_ELE` in all the places of `0x64`.

Comment: is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: @WedaPashi, Updated the answer to answer your question